Upload file to Google Drive in specific folder location Using Postman
I have a requirement to upload the pdf files to google drive in specific folder. for that I am referring to the google drive documentation

I am able to configure the setup as per the documentation but when i tried to upload the file is getting uploaded with untitled and also its not able to upload the file in specified folder.
I have setup the below Postman setup for the multipart configuration. please check and confirm on any changes that would be needed.
URL:https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart
Method: Post
Body: form-data
key values:
Metadata: {
  "name":"pdftest1.pdf",
  "description":"This is a test pdf",
  "parents": ["1YSJmegLkWfnBcsOoqmC8pkVYJXmn1RFV"]
}

type: text
file: attached the pdf file and opted for file option
screenshots:



can some one please provide me a valid collection if your able to upload the file with proper name to Gdrive via postman using multipart

Try removing uploadType if it works i will tell you why.

@LindaLawton-DaImTo I have tried it and it's not working.
